# razor in asp.net (c# + html) retrieve value from checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a simple view with a checkbox at the bottom:

```
   @model Application.Areas.Cms.Models.ProduktBeispielViewModel
    @{
        ViewBag.PopupHeadline = "Produktbeispiele";
        ViewBag.PopupSubHeadline = Model.Item != null ? Model.Item.NameInCurrentLang : "";
        ViewBag.HideLanguageComparison = true;
    }
    
    @section TabMenu
    {
        <ul>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ProduktbeispieleEditor", new { id = Model.Item.Id })" class="Active">Einstellungen</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Image", "ProduktbeispieleEditor", new { id = Model.Item.Id })">Bild</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
    
    
    
    
    <form action="@Url.Action("SaveIndex")" method="POST" id="idForm">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoCloseWindow)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Item.Id)

<checkbox/>

</form>
```

I have this Index:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, int categoryId = 0, bool autoclosewindow=false,bool refreshOpener=false)
{
    var model = LoadModel(id, categoryId);
    model.AutoCloseWindow = autoclosewindow;
    model.RefreshSequenceInOverview = refreshOpener;
    

    foreach (var lang in new LanguageManager().GetItems())
    {
        ...
    }


    return View(model);
}
```

And ofc I have my model containing the data properties.

I can already display values bound inside my model in my view but I cannot seem to go the way back, meaning if the user checks the checkbox, how do I retrieve that is has been checked?
(Same would go for an editor or entry field)

How can I access the data from my checkbox?

EDIT:

I already have a form of which the checkbox is a child:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SaveIndex")" method="POST" id="idForm">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoCloseWindow)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Item.Id)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Test2)
```

But when I set a stoppoint at the corresponding function:

```
    public ActionResult SaveIndex(Product item, List<GeneralLanguageEntry> languages, bool autoclosewindow = false)
    {
...
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { autoclosewindow = autoclosewindow, refreshOpener = true, id = productFromDb.Id });
    }
```

The model is not returned here... So i cannot see my altered checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a rendered control from the html helper rather than just putting a checkbox on the page. This will bind the control to the property in your model.

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.YourBoolValue)

Make sure you have a method that will accept your post data when the form is submitted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveIndex(Product item)
...
```

Comment: Ok, I was just able to display the value from my model onto a checkbox rendered as you described. But how can I now access this checkbox again inside my c# class, so that I can see wheter the user checked or unchecked the checkbox? :)

Comment: you need a submit button. When the user submits the form, the model is posted back to your controller. You would typically have another action with the same name but accepting your model as its parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my edits to my question, I think we are very close :)

Comment: maybe add the [HttpPost] attribute above the method

Comment: Great, you're welcome